# How can I change the port for a published Blazor Server project?

Tags: port, blazor, kestrel

I published my Blazor project.  Then when I run it from the command line via 'dotnet myapp.dll' it gives this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
```

I have changed the port in the launchsettings.json but this is with no effect. It still uses the port 5000. Where can i change the port for the compiled blazor project?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the UseUrls() method like below in Program.cs.  In this case I picked port 8700.

```c#
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:8700");
        });
```

Then when I run 'dotnet myapp.dll' from the command line, I can see the Kestrel output like this:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:8700
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The listen address including port can be overridden with the `--urls` argument or via the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable:

```bash
dotnet myapp.dll --urls http://localhost:8700
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I changed the target of myapp.exe shortcut.

for example:

```
E:\apps\app01\myapp.exe  --urls http://192.168.1.100:5010
```

[image]

[blazor](/questions/tagged/blazor) [port](/questions/tagged/port) [url](/questions/tagged/url)